Pgbouncer Server Connection Crashed Error
Pgbouncer returns this error frequently on many of my database connections. I can't figure out what exactly is causing this error.
2024-06-12 13:02:23.005 +03 [2865569] LOG C-0x56059d2f0410: db_name/user_name@IP_Adrr:64507 closing because: server conn crashed? (age=151s)
2024-06-12 13:02:23.005 +03 [2865569] WARNING C-0x56059d2f0410: db_name/user_name@IP_Adrr:64507 pooler error: server conn crashed?
2024-06-12 13:04:41.649 +03 [2865569] LOG S-0x56059d2e5e30: db_name/user_name@IP_Adrr:5438 closing because: server conn crashed? (age=9s)
2024-06-12 13:04:41.649 +03 [2865569] LOG C-0x56059d2e9900: db_name/user_name@IP_Adrr:12012 closing because: server conn crashed? (age=176s)
2024-06-12 13:04:41.649 +03 [2865569] WARNING C-0x56059d2e9900: db_name/user_name@IP_Adrr:12012 pooler error: server conn crashed?
2024-06-12 13:06:11.077 +03 [2865569] LOG S-0x56059d2e0480: db_name/user_name@IP_Adrr:5438 closing because: server conn crashed? (age=53s)
2024-06-12 13:06:11.077 +03 [2865569] LOG C-0x56059d2f50a0: db_name/user_name@IP_Adrr:11403 closing because: server conn crashed? (age=91s)
2024-06-12 13:06:11.077 +03 [2865569] WARNING C-0x56059d2f50a0: db_name/user_name@IP_Adrr:11403 pooler error: server conn crashed?
2024-06-12 13:24:14.772 +03 [2865569] LOG S-0x56059d2ffb40: db_name/user_name@IP_Adrr:5433 closing because: server conn crashed? (age=1s)
2024-06-12 13:24:14.772 +03 [2865569] LOG C-0x56059d30e110: db_name/user_name@IP_Adrr:27698 closing because: server conn crashed? (age=18s)
2024-06-12 13:24:14.772 +03 [2865569] WARNING C-0x56059d30e110: db_name/user_name@IP_Adrr:27698 pooler error: server conn crashed?

I couldn't find a clear configuration parameter for this particular error. What is the solution to this error?
Postgresql Version: 13.3
Pgbouncer Version: 1.15
Thanks.
Addition;
When I filter my database clusters according to the time of the error logs of pgbouncer, I saw that it prints the same log every time: " invalid frontend message type", "invalid message format"
Detailed Information;
    pgbouncer;
    2024-06-12 17:57:16.850 +03 [3082827] LOG S-0x5614e6fb7f70: dbname/username@Ip_Adrr:5438 closing because: server conn crashed? (age=0s)
    2024-06-12 17:57:16.850 +03 [3082827] LOG C-0x7f43e43ac9f0: dbname/username@Ip_Adrr:58547 closing because: server conn crashed? (age=54s)
    2024-06-12 17:57:16.850 +03 [3082827] WARNING C-0x7f43e43ac9f0: dbname/username@Ip_Adrr:58547 pooler error: server conn crashed?
    2024-06-12 17:57:16.857 +03 [3082827] LOG S-0x5614e6fb4230: dbname/username@Ip_Adrr:5438 closing because: server conn crashed? (age=7s)
    2024-06-12 17:57:16.857 +03 [3082827] LOG C-0x5614e6ff4810: dbname/username@Ip_Adrr:34049 closing because: server conn crashed? (age=0s)
    2024-06-12 17:57:16.857 +03 [3082827] WARNING C-0x5614e6ff4810: dbname/username@Ip_Adrr:34049 pooler error: server conn crashed?

And when I checked the logs of my database cluster at 17:57:16;
    postgres;
    time=2024-06-12 17:57:16 +03,pid=3094030 db=dbname,usr=username,client=Ip_Adrr FATAL:  invalid frontend message type 54
    time=2024-06-12 17:57:16 +03,pid=3094044 db=dbname,usr=username,client=Ip_Adrr ERROR:  invalid message format
    time=2024-06-12 17:57:16 +03,pid=3094044 db=dbname,usr=username,client=Ip_Adrr FATAL:  invalid frontend message type 50

Apart from this log, I did not catch any error logs in my database clusters.

What is in the PostgreSQL server's log file?

@jjanes I have attached the log of my postgresql database clusters to the question, please have a look.

I'm guessing that that is a bug in pgbouncer.  I would note that 1.15 is quite old.  Can you upgrade it?

my databases are currently overloaded. I'll take downtime and update pgbouncer.
So what should I pay attention to in the update? Will I need to refresh the config file during the update? If I do this, I need to back up the config file.

I think it should just be a matter of installing the new binary, and then starting that rather than the old one.  The same conf file should still work.  But of course you should be backing that up anyway.  The details might depend on how you installed (like, what OS and package manager and repo).
